# keep formatting entered in asp.net textbox (carriage return, new line, etc)

Tags: asp.net, textbox, text-formatting

I have a textbox using multiline mode and when I create the stored procedure parameter for updating I use `Server.HtmlEncode` on the textbox value. I can copy the content from the data record into Notepad and it shows the spaces where the user has pressed the Enter key for new paragraphs.

When displaying that content on a page (not a textbox for editing; just assigning the content to a Literal control), it has all the text run together.

I have done some searches about using Replace and different escape sequences or `Environment.NewLine`. I am still confused about how to have the text display as the user entered it.

Comment: The problem is that HTML sees a newline as "just whitespace" and mostly ignores it. In a "view source" you will still see those newlines. Ditto for extra "formatting spaces". So you will need to replace newlines with a html-linebreak, see AndyM's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using C# you can do the following when you display the string on the page

```
theStringYouWantToFormat.Replace(char.ConvertFromUtf32(13),"<br/>")
```

When you call `Server.HtmlEncode` on the value you grab from a text box it'll look at the text and encode any HTML tags contained in that text box so for example `<script></script>` would be encoded to `&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Just to clarify, should I do this when the content is updated thereby not needing any formatting when displaying the content to a visitor?

Comment: You can do it either when the content is saved or when it is displayed. Personally I'm not a big fan of having HTML tags inside my database unless I have to but there are plenty of reason to do so. The thing to keep in mind is if the data is ever going to be used outwith a web page, merged into a word document for example, then you have HTML tags inside the data which will need removed and when you come to edit the information you will need to do the reverse of what I've posted above so it's six and one half dozen of the other.

Comment: Andy: That is good thing to keep in mind about displaying the content in some format other than a web page. Thankfully I don't have that "problem" with this specific project :)

Comment: Hi James, just updated my comment. If you do store the HTML in the database when you set the content back into a text box for updating you will need to do the opposite of what I posted above for displaying on the front end so it would be myTextBox.Text = theStringYouWantToFormat.Replace("<br/>",char.ConvertFromUtf32(13)).

Comment: Andy, Thanks for providing that information. We noticed that was happening. Just to be clear, what would be the best way to handle these : 1) getting the text input to store in the database, 2) displaying on the page the visitor to see and 3) how the text is shown in the edit content textbox? I would prefer that the editor not see the any html tags or code in the textbox field. Thanks. James

Comment: I just reread your comments and believe that I answered my last question :)

Comment: Hi James, personally I would do the following 1) store the data entered into the text box as is in the database 2) display the data as outlined in my initial answer, replacing line breaks with br's 3) the info from the database can be set straight into the text box OR you can do the following 1) replace line breaks with br's before you save to the database 2) display straight from the database to the page 3) set the database content into the text box replacing br's with line breaks. I tend to go with option 1 but a lot of our data is displayed in non web apps so HTML inside it is a no go

Comment: If this is still monitored I have question for Andy: I have a same situation, but on the formating end I'm using the Eval("message") in the text property of the label. Is there a way to combine the formating you suggested with this? Thanks.